# Problems with bootup

Tags: boot

After installing elementary os I booted with a live Cd to resize my partition and ever since the boot up is not taking place normally.
Sometimes it freezes with a blank screen.
Sometimes it shows errors like something related to busybox etc.
Please help I am new to elementary OS and I am hating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you broke your installation.

it's probably going to be easier to reinstall it with correct partitions at this point considering you just installed it so there's nothing to migrate.

and you should know that it is impossible for people to help you if you aren't more specific about your error messages. take a picture with your phone if they go past to quick to write.